# What are those installed unknown programs?

Tags: uwp, windows-10

Does anyone know what are these programs (GUIDs)? I belive they are part of UWP programming because when I run debug at Visual Studio, these programs appear in "Installed Programs".

Also, can't see in Windows 10's Installed Programs but CCleaner.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I have installed Visual Studio, perform same operations as you do. And I dont see such a thing... probably you have a problem somewhere else.

Comment: When you run your program from VS, it actually deploys the app to your machine. I belive these "unknown" things are part of it.

Comment: Really weird. I tried to test it with opened CCleaner - still nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have guessed, most of these "unknown programs" are generated form Visual Studio when you deploy or debug UWP apps. And some of them are created by XAML Designer to provide synchronized Design view. These apps won't be listed in **Apps & features**. One possible way to find them is using **PowerShell** with the following command:

```
Get-AppxPackage | ? {$_.IsDevelopmentMode -eq $True}
```

This command works because all these "unknown programs" are installed in development mode.

And then if you want to uninstall them, you can add `Remove-AppxPackage` command like:

```
Get-AppxPackage | ? {$_.IsDevelopmentMode -eq $True} | Remove-AppxPackage
```

After this there should be no "unknown programs" in CCleaner.

Comment: Your code works but there some apps still can't delete. Are they related to UWP development? Screenshot => http://imgur.com/DfOT8F2